# Angular2/Nativescript: Is it possible to have content contained in a GridLayout column wrap to the next line?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a very basic Nativescript app.  I have an issue using GridLayout accurately.  i'm trying to re-create a table from an Angular2 web app using GridLayout. I get The contents of my GridLayout from a local API and it's always going to be different.  Whenever a name is too long it gets partially displayed and then postfixed with a ... Also I have 4 columns and sometimes when the first 3 is too wide the fourth doesn't get shown at all.  Is there any way I can set a static width for a column but then have any word that doesn't fit in that column wrrap to the next line?  If so how can I go about it?

Comment: Have you tried adding `textWrap="true"` to those elements that get cut off by `...`?

Comment: @Eddy Verbruggen Thanks a lot that did it!:)  Please add your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Glad that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `textWrap="true"` to those elements that get cut off by `...`?